# How to find the local maximum of an image in JuliaImages?

Tags: image-processing, julia

I want to find the local maximum of a distance transform to make a marker for watershed.
According to the [docs](https://juliaimages.org/latest/function_reference/#ImageFiltering.MapWindow.mapwindow) the function `mapwindow` should do it.
However, when I try:

```
using Images
using ImageFiltering
mapwindow(maximum, myimage)
```

I get this error:

```
MethodError: no method matching mapwindow(::typeof(maximum), ::Array{Float64,2})
```

Comment: You're missing info about the window size, see `?mapwindow`.

Answer (score 0):

I just think you have to make sure that your function works correctly on the data that's passed to it.

```
using Images
using ImageFiltering
using TestImages

im = testimage("lighthouse")
```

[image: lighthouse]

```
f(a) = (first(a) + last(a))/2 # adds opposite corners

mw = mapwindow(f, im, (3, 3))
```

[image: lighthouse after]